# Doctoring cake mix to make it denser

Tags: cake

I am being lazy and making a cake from a box mix but I want it to be denser. Would adding more flour or less egg accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re looking for a pound cake like density, add a box of instant pudding in with the cake mix.

(This was a recommendation from an instructor from a cake decorating class that I took 15+ years ago, but I’ve never done it myself, or at least I don’t remember doing it)